# Do I need a custom controller for a model with foreign keys in devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, rails-activerecord

I have 3 tables: staff, address, country. Country belongs to address and address belongs to staff. The staff table has all the columns needed for devise and the foreign key to address.

Do I need a custom controller to save all the data with one form? How can I accomplish this task?
Is it enough to make a form that refers to the address and country table and add the nested attributes to the model staff for address and to model address for country. I have some problems understanding how devise really works.

Comment: Devise is useful for an authenticated session (login and logout) and user management (sign up, delete account, forgotten password). Is "staff" someone who signs up and logs in? (Usually called "User" or Account.") If so, are separate tables needed for address and country? Does a "staff" have more than one address or country? If not, just add address, city, state, country as attributes to the staff model. See the [Rails and Devise](https://github.com/RailsApps/rails-devise) example app for adding a name attribute to a user model.

Answer (score 0):

use `has_many` in your staff model.

Comment: This should be right. I'll test it tonight. Thank you.

Comment: I tryed it and it works so far. My only problem is now that it doesnt create the submodel the proper way to then assign the new address_id to the staff model. So it say that the address_id cant be null.